# why there are 2 drawable folder in res folder in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

[image: So Iwas pasting some image in the drawable folder and I found that there are 2 folders as you can see in below picture]

So I was pasting some image in the drawable folder and I found that there are 2 folders as you can see in below picture
one is **drawable** and another is **drawable-v24**

So my questions are

1. why there are 2 drawable folders ?
2. whats the diff. ?
3. Do we really need them ?
4. any additional information is deeply appreciated .  :)

Answer (score 2):

The drawable folder is the default folder.  The drawable-v24 applies to only those devices with Android v24 or higher-  any file in that directory will be used instead of the file with the same name in drawable on the applicable versions.  Do you need them both?  Only if you want different images on newer devices, or if there's some feature of v24 and higher that you want to take advantage of where available.  If not you can safely delete it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many drawable folder types based on many factors,

- **Android OS version**, ex: *drawable-V21, drawable-V22, drawable-v23*...etc
- **Density pixels** - Refer https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

This different folder types are used to access the images for particular needs, say if you have to load a small size icon in Lollipop OS and a different size icon in all other OS, you have to use **drawable-V21** for lollipop and normal drawable folder for all others.

Another case based on the resolution of mobile phones, quality will vary on images, example: **drawable-hdpi** images supports Full HD mobiles, whereas **drawable-xxhdpi** support QuadHD mobiles and so on..